# How to make icinga2 to alarm only 10min+ downtime?

Tags: icinga2

I have the problem that the connection between the host running icinga2, and between the actually checked server machines, is a little bit... non-deterministic.

Thus, sometimes - every day for some minutes, in an unpredictable time - all the hosts and services seem went down by the icinga.

I don't want it. I think the best solution to work around this problem, if I could somehow set up a *minimal downtime length*, for example, 10 minutes.

Alarms should be created only if a downtime is longer as this value.

The obvious side-effect (alarms get this delay + lack of monitoring for the short network downtime) is not a problem for me.

Comment: Alternatively, any other solution is acceptable, if it solves the main problem (makes icinga to avoid false alarms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `check_interval` and `retry_interval` in combination with `max_check_attempts`

```
template Host "10mindowntime" {
  max_check_attempts = 10
  check_interval = 1m
  retry_interval = 1m
}
```

You can change the times and attempts to fit any level of granularity you want after the ten mins is up.